# Phonegap - common and different assets

Tags: cordova, assets

I'm a total n00b at phonegap and honestly the documentation is a bit poor about this:

There are N+1 folders containing assets:

- /www (one main directory)
- (platform)/assets/www (N directories, one for each installed platform)

Is there a way, for an asset (say a css, image or html file) to be loaded from the current platform and, if not exists, loaded from the /www directory?

My case is this: I have an html file for my screen and many additional assets. I would like such assets (e.g. css/platformdependent.css) be loaded from the /platforms/android/assets/www/css/platformdependent.css or /platforms/iphone/assets/www/css/platformdependent.css depending on the current device deploy.

In contrast, some images could exist in /www/images I'd like to have in common, and other images are platform-specific like /platforms/android/assets/www/images (or the corresponding ios).

I would like to do so without copying my files from /www to each respective /assets/www

My goal is to not have redundant files but keep only one copy from files which should be the same and have different platform files for files that should differ from platform.

**Q**: Is there a way to have such files without copying the files as I told?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`www` is the main directory

`platform/.../www` contains the content of `www` + the content of the specific platform content in `merges/NAME_OF_PLATFORM`

so for example if you have a special share icon for Android, you can place it in `/merges/android/img` and it will replace the common image in the `www` when using the `build` command

Look there : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html, section "Customize each platform"

Comment: could you help me here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24540972/phonegap-merge-directories-assets-not-being-merged