# Phonegap merge directories - assets not being merged

Tags: cordova, merge, assets

I'm a total n00b at PhoneGap (version: 3.4). Currently I have a project structure like:

```
.cordova
+---config.json
hooks
+---README.md
merges
+---android
    +---js
        +---index.js
platforms
+---.gitkeep
plugins
+---org.apache.cordova.device (content: the plugin sources, doc, and data)
+---android.json (content: plugins config for android)
www
+---css (content: many assets here)
+---img (content: many assets here)
+---js (content: many assets here, siblings of index.js)
    +---index.js (a default file intended to be overriden by the merged index.js file)
+---res (content: resources for splashscreen and stuff configured in config.xml)
+---index.html
+---config.xml
+---icon.png
```

My intention is to have many files being overriden by platform specific files (in this case, android), so I created a `merges/android` directory for my custom android assets.

Contents of index.js (base):

```
var app = {
    selectDevice: function() {
        window.alert('using default');
    },
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.selectDevice, false);
    }
};
```

Contents of index.js (to-merge):

```
var app = {
    selectDevice: function() {
        window.alert('using android');
    },
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.selectDevice, false);
    }
};
```

Contents of index.html (the only-and-common html file for every platform):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <title>1001Carros</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.alert('initializing...');
            app.initialize();
            window.alert('initialization was run.');
        </script>
        <div id="log">
            <button id="clickme" value="Click Me"></button>
            pantalla principal
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The filesystem structure I detailed here is the state of my current repository (notes: empty folders have dummy .gitkeep files so they exist in the repository - this is specially true for the platforms directory, which is currently empty).

However, when I push my contents to my repo and pull-and-rebuild in http://build.phonegap.com, I had two scenarios:

1. In the first try, I did not create an `index.js` file in the base www directory, but just in the merges/android directory. Result: the file was missing (i.e. it's content, which was an alert being shown inside the deviceReady event -telling that the current platform is android- was never executed, and subsequent code neither -message: initialization was run-, which is the result of a `ReferenceError` when trying to call `app.initialize()`).
2. In the second try, I create the `index.js` to be the default under `www/js` when no file was merged. Result: the message printed was 'using default'.

My conclusion: the file was never merged.

**My question**: Why? Should I create an explicit platforms/android directory (well: platform) in order to get my files merged? or should build.phonegap.com do it automatically when I tell to rebuild the android application?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

The `merges` folder is meant for ressources like images or css, not that much for entire JS in my opinion. Instead, I advise you to add the Device plugin and test `device.platform` against "android" for a different behaviour on those platforms.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.platform

You asked if you should create a `platform/android` directory. This is a weird question because if you are doing this right, you should be using the `build` command and that directory should be created by itself! Then in the `platform/android/assets/www` you should find your files merged, nowhere else.

Comment: I noticed the Phonegap Build service does not support MERGEs. I noticed that `phonegap build android` neither supports merges. Finally: noticed that `cordova build android` (appending `--release` or not) supports merges. Had to have BOTH command lines installed.