# How should I do the platform specific code managements(SVN) for hybrid mobile apps?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, svn, titanium

I'm developing hybrid mobile application using PhoneGap & Titanium for Android, iOS and Windows mobile platforms. The application is relatively big and contains platform specific code due to it's nature.

As an example assume that there is a file called `main.js`. Should the `main.js` contain code belongs to all three platforms and use commenting when building application for each platform. When I'm building for Android comment out the code related to iOS and vice verse.

How should I do the code managements in SVN?

- Should I use separate SVN branches for each OS?
- Should I include all the code in a single branch and use commenting?
- Other alternatives?

Comment: I agree with Raymond about the merges folder to kepp plaform-specific code. About the svn part, I advise to svn ignore all the platform-specific folders (platforms/android, platforms/ios...) and let each developer create the platform after the checkout (and note that the platform should be deleted/re-created after any update to the plugins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit awkward. Your title talks about using SVN, which provides source code management for versioning, etc, but your question asks about platform specific code which is a bit different.

If you focus on the aspect of handling platform specific code, you've got a few ways to handle it in PhoneGap/Cordova. (I can't speak for Titanium.)

1. You can use merges to automatically modify code on a per platform basis. See the docs here (way towards the bottom) - http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface
2. You could use Device plugin (http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.device) to sniff the device and do something specific per platform.
3. You could use hooks to modify the code per platform too. Merges is simpler, but hooks give you more power.

## Update

[Phonegap merge directories - assets not being merged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24540972/phonegap-merge-directories-assets-not-being-merged)

Comment: Referring to your option 1, 2here should the `merges` folder reside? Should it be in the `www`. Please provide me the full path and folder structure.

Comment: Merges is at the root of your project. It is not created by default with a new project, so just make it manually. Then under "merges", add ios, android, etc.

Comment: @RaymondCamden it's strange, I was sure merges folder was created with new projects, I was even sure it was there when I created my main project couple of years ago... any idea if it's actually never been there by default or if it was removed at some time?

Comment: I kinda thought it was there in new projects, but maybe it got removed. I did some tests today (I'm writing a book on Cordova and am currently in this section :) and confirmed the folder isn't there in a new project.

Answer (score 1):

Dont write redundant or comment and uncomment code, use cordova device plugin and check for device platform  and write there if something platform specific.

example:

```
     if ( device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' ){
     // write here android specific code
      }
```

Comment: If i do this I will get: 

Uncaught ReferenceError: device is not defined